# Disable link button after click on it in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I want to disable link button after clicking of it and enable other. Toggle enable/ disable between both link buttons using c#.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to Click event of this buttons and set Enabled property to true or false.

```
  void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     // First enable all buttons
     btn1.Enabled = true;
     btn2.Enabled = true;

     // Then disable the clicked button
     (sender as Control).Enabled = false;

     ...
  }
```

This is just an example of how you can do this. Can be optimized...

Answer (score 1):

To disable a link button you should assign false to its [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled.aspx) property:

```
button.Enabled = false;
```

There is also an example how to hook OnClick event in the linked MSDN article.

Comment: my page contains links like this-

<a href="page1">One</a>
<a href="page2">Two</a>

so. how to do? using javascript or css?

Comment: My answer was in therms of ASP.NET and C#. For Javascript answer you should reformulate the question.